# Raycast how to deal with more than one object same layer

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision, raycasting

I am using raycast to detect that the player is grounded after a jump, my problem is that some times the raycast is not detecting that the player is grounded and it is.

This is my code for the raycasting:

```
void IsGrounded()
    {

        RaycastHit hit;
        int mask = 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Floor");


        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out hit, 0.1f, mask))
        {

            isGrounded = true;
            checkGround = false;
            Debug.Log("is grounded");

            if (!myAudioSource.isPlaying)
            {
                myAudioSource.Play();
            }            
        }
        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, hit.point, Color.red);


    }
```

Here is my problem:

[image: Raycast not detecting ground]

The character is in the ground but the ray is still not detecting it.
Sometimes this same location will detect and others it won't.

Comment: So I just realized that the reason why is always drawing to the original position is that the ray is not hitting anything at this point, so it is using the default position. Will update the question with this information.

Comment: You should edit your question to remove the (patently false) supposition that Unity can't find all the objects on the Floor layer and replace it with what you wrote in that comment.

Comment: Will do, forgot to do that